# From a D7(#9) to E6

Tags: theory, chord-theory, chord-progressions, roman-numerals

I am trying to identify the resolution between the D7#9 to an E6. In roman numeral would I consider the resolve as: **bVII7 to I**? Also, does the #9(*F*) of D and 6(*C#*) affect the kind of resolution this may be? Does this have a name or is this common? Thanks in advance my musical geniuses!

Comment: May I ask what key this is in? That determines what "I" is in the Roman numerals, which therefore helps clarify what the D and E chords would be.

Comment: The key of this song is E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `♭VII` to `I` it's at least potentially a *backdoor progression.*

If the 'normal' progression to `I` is `ii V I`, then backdoor progression does is with borrowed chords `iv ♭VII I`.

Whatever comes before your `♭VII♯9` might make a difference whether to call it a backdoor progression.

In terms of 'how it work', the idea would be `♭VII` is used in place of the normal `V`, it works because the `^2` and `^4` scale degree are in either chord. In other words `^2` and `^4` could be harmonized with either `V` or `♭VII` in a satisfying move to `I`.

Comment: Also, the riff of parallel-voiced flatVII7-VII7-I occurs with some frequency...

Comment: The preceding chord is a Fsus4

Comment: @DouglasCHowe, is that `F` _natural_ sus4? This is a progression you wrote?

Comment: Yes this is a progression I wrote. And the F is natural.